# Is it correct to use 'could' to describe past permission?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense, modality

Recently I`ve been revising my knowledge about the verb *could*. I know that *could* is used as the past form of *can* to describe a general ability in the past. E.g.

> I could  work 10 hours a day when I was younger.

For specific situations in the past "to be able to" is preffered, though. E.g.

> I was able to get out of the car before it exploded.

Yet, there is another aspect of the modal verb *could* that got me puzzled, and that is *could* as the verb used to express permission in the past. I know it is fine to use the expression "to be allowed to" in that context. E.g.

> Children were allowed to use calculators during the test.

My question is: Can I use *could* for expressing both: a general past permission and a specific past permission? For example:

(general permission)

> Children could use their mobile phones only during breaks, not during lessons.

(specific permission)

> Even though I was on the train, I could smoke.

Comment: Yup! Both of those sentences make sense!

Comment: "Even though I was on the train, I could smoke"  --  This has a taste of being more about having the ability to smoke than permission.

Comment: @BaileyS Why is that? And what phrase/verb/expression would you use instead?

Comment: @BaileyS I disagree at least for colloquial English. the can vs may distinction (ability vs permission) is less rigid in informal forms of English. But yes, in formal/traditional English, "I could smoke" is ability and "I might smoke" could be permission. It's easy to see how those get blended

Comment: "I was able to get out of the car before it exploded." With this sentence, using "was able to" specifically emphasizes not only that the speaker had the ability to get out of the car, but that they did. "I could get out of the car before it exploded" only really implies the ability existed, but less so that they actually did.

Comment: @eques Permission is sometimes implicit in situations where something _could_ be done, but there are other situations where permission is not relevant, or a lack of permission does not affect the subject. (ie. _The inmate could escape from jail._)  The example sentences are all correct, but there is more subtlety to the difference, and they are not perfectly equivalent sentences.

Comment: @BaileyS I was coming from the opposite direction. You indicated that "I could smoke" was more ability than permission. From the context, permission seems more sensible to presume, but traditionally could/can is ability not permission.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *could* can indicate both ability and permission, just like *can* can.

> He could leave the room

could indicate either past ability or permission, and it would take context to determine which.

All your example sentences are correct.